# How to show a composable dialog atleast for 2 seconds?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-stateflow

I am new into jetpack compose and I really wanted to know how I can display a composable dialog atleast for 2 seconds. Currently it hides very quickly which does not even get displayed on the screen. I'm displaying it for a local logic due to that it's getting hidden so fast.

By using below code, I can display the dialog and disable the touching outside or pressing back button. The dialog just still is visible on the top of view hierarchy but it gets hide very quickly.

```
 @Composable
fun LoadingBox(modifier: Modifier) {
    Dialog(
        onDismissRequest = {},
        properties = DialogProperties(dismissOnClickOutside = false)
    ) {
        Surface(
            elevation = 4.dp,
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(dimensionResource(R.dimen.stroke_size))
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = modifier
                    .background(color = Dark_Gray)
                    .padding(
                    start = dimensionResource(R.dimen.view_padding_start),
                    end = dimensionResource(R.dimen.view_padding_start)
                )
                .height(140.dp)
                .fillMaxHeight(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            LoadingAnimation()
            Text(
                text = stringResource(id = R.string.loading_message),
                fontWeight = FontWeight.ExtraBold,
                fontSize = 15.sp,
                color = Gray,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(top = 30.dp)
                    .clipToBounds()
                    .testTag(Constants.TestTag.LOADER)
                    )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using below Singleton class's function to make visible and hide the dialog.

```
 /*
* Loading Dialog Functionality
*/
val loadingStateIndicator = MutableLiveData<LoadingState>()
fun onLoadingStateChanged(state: LoadingState) {
    when (state) {
        LoadingState.LOADING -> {
            _uiState.value = _uiState.value.copy(
                loading = true
            )
        }
        LoadingState.LOADED -> {
            _uiState.value = _uiState.value.copy(
                loading = false
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Is using of Timer.schedule good practice or not in this scenario?

Comment: You mean you want to show it for a minimum amount of time even if the loading is completed faster than that?

Comment: It's already completing so fast. I'm unable to see the dialog in positive scenario. I had to comment next screen's navController to see it.

Comment: Isn’t that a sign you don’t need it in the first place? Why make the user suffer through an unnecessary extra load screen? But regarding your question, Timer is not suitable. Composables must not have side effects unless you use a Compose Effect, namely LaunchedEffect. Since LaunchedEffect is a coroutine, it can call delay(), which is a lot simpler than Timer anyway. You can have a MutableState Boolean for forcing the dialog to stay open that is set true when you first show the dialog, and in a LaunchedEffect you set it false after delay. Show the dialog when either state is true.

Comment: I totally agree with you but as I'm new into Jetpack compose so wanted to know appropriate solution. As I have this delay requirement in my ViewModel so I can use delay using ViewModelScope also.

Answer (score 1):

This is the strategy I was suggesting in my comments. I think if you *were* going to do something like this, the delay should be handled on the UI side, not in the ViewModel, because the delay is a UI detail and not part of the model's state.

Here, it keeps the dialog open for a minimum of two seconds, but if loading takes longer than two seconds, then it would immediately close the dialog when loading is done.

This is trickier than I initially thought. Maybe there's a cleaner way I haven't thought of. I haven't tested this.

```
// In some composable:
val loadingState by viewModel.loadingStateIndicator.observeAsState(LoadingState.LOADING)
val lastDialogOpenTime = remember(loadingState) { 
    if(loadingState == LoadingState.LOADING) System.currentTimeMillis() else 0L
}
val now = System.currentTimeMillis()
var shouldShowDialog by remember(loadingState) { 
    mutableStateOf(loadingState == LoadingState.LOADING || now > lastDialogOpenTime + 2000L)
}
LaunchedEffect(loadingState) {
    if(LoadingState == LoadingState.LOADED && shouldShowDialog) {
        delay(lastDialogOpenTime + 2000L - now) 
        shouldShowDialog = false
    }
}

if (shouldShowDialog) {
    LoadingBox()
}
```

Or maybe this could be done more simply using a flow. You can create a Flow that has a lagging state change. I haven't tested this either

```
val laggedLoadingStateIndicator by remember { 
    viewModel.loadingStateIndicator.asFlow()
        .buffer() // I'm not sure if this is necessary
        .transform {
            emit(it)
            if (it == LoadingState.LOADING) {
                delay(2000)
            }
        }
        .collectAsState(LoadingState.LOADED)
}

if (laggedLoadingStateIndicator == LoadingState.LOADING) {
    LoadingBox()
}
```